# Convert array_push to brackets

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I want to convert the code I have using array_push to brackets, its for creating json

```
array_push($arr,
    ['A'=>['B' => $value_b],
   'X'=>$value_x,
    'T'=>$value_y
]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this,

```
$arr[] = ['A'=>['B' => $value_b], 'X'=>$value_x, 'T'=>$value_y];
```

And just so you know, both `array_push()` and `[]` serves the exact same purpose, it'll make no difference in the creation of JSON string.